# How to use the autocomplete feature for VBA function in Excel 2007 with Excel Add-In (.xlam)

Tags: autocomplete, excel, excel-2007, vba

I created a function in VBA. I want Excel 2007 to show the Autocomplete when writing this function in the cell's Excel.
Detail as
[image]

How to use the autocomplete feature for VBA function in Excel 2007 with Excel Add-In (.xlam)?

ps.

In Excel 2010, the autocomplete works

In Excel 2007 with Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet (.xlsm), the autocomplete works. The test file [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/50358043/test%20autocomplete.xlsm).

But, in Excel 2007 with Excel Add-In (.xlam), the autocomplete  NOT works. The test file [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/50358043/test%20autocomplete.xlam).

Comment: This has been cross-posted to Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/449079/how-to-use-the-autocomplete-feature-for-vba-function-in-excel-2007-with-excel-ad, so I'm closing this version.